# How to decode this json with php?

Tags: php, json

I have this json code:

```
$cars = '{
"CarBenz": 
[
{
"Car": "Benz",
"Color": "Black"
}
]
}';
$json = json_decode($cars , true);
```

how to print `Benz` in screen?

```
print $json['Car'];
```

`$json['Car']` nothing show anything.

Comment: `echo $json['CarBenz'][0]['Car'];`

Comment: var_dump($json) reveals you the structure - you have array of cars, not object as a value in the "carBenz" key - Its an array, so to get 1st element use [0] and next dimension of the array will be key (car) as Kim Alekxander wrote

Answer (score 2):

To see the type of a variable (and how an object or array is built up) you can use `var_dump($json)`.

In this case, that will give:

```
array(1) {
  ["CarBenz"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Car"]=>
      string(4) "Benz"
      ["Color"]=>
      string(5) "Black"
    }
  }
}
```

So you need to do `$json['CarBenz'][0]['Car']`.

Answer (score 1):

First you can `var_dump` your decoded json string and you can see the array with the structure.

I think you forgot to access the `CarBenz` element first.

```
echo $json['CarBenz'][0]['Car'];
```

If you need all elements in `CarBenz` you have to iterate over them. Something like that:

```
foreach($json['CarBenz'] as $car) {
    echo $car;
}
```